# shortest distance between vector and point

Tags: trigonometry

Referring to the figure below, I am trying to compute the distance between $(x, y)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$ where $(x, y)$ and $\theta$ are known.  $(x_1, y_1)$ will lie on the $45^\circ$ line (that extends from $+/- $ infinity).  What's the shortest distance between $(x, y)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$?

I have a lot of data that I'm trying to correlate between two datasets and I want to use this to filter outliers.  A sample that correlates perfectly will lie on the $45^\circ$ line with $y$-intercept of $0$.
I want to sort the data from the points that are closest to the line to points which are furthest away.  Best solution would be the one most computationally efficient (prefer multiplication over trig functions).

[image]

Comment: Sketching...what looks like an acute angle appears as marked  right angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest distance between a point $P(x_p,y_p)$ and a line $ax+by+c=0$ is:

\begin{equation}
d=\frac{|ax_p+by_p+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
\end{equation}

In this case we have the line $x-y=0$ so $a=1$, $b=-1$, $c=0$:

\begin{equation}
d=\frac{|x_p-y_p|}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{equation}

Comment: I plugged in a few points and that seems to work.  I'll award you the answer as your solution does not involve any trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x,y,\theta$ are known, the shortest distance should be $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin(\theta-45^\circ)$$

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich I didn't ask a question! I just gave an answer , leaving the  OP to think about..

Comment: @Qwerty: True, but you answered in an interogative way, leaving the impression that you yourself are asking instead of answering, or that you are unsure about your own answer.

Comment: @AlexM. There you go.

Answer (score 1):

Let $D$ be your distance.

we have

$$\sin(\theta-\frac{\pi}{4})=\frac{D}{b}$$

and

$$D=b\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\sin(\theta)-\cos(\theta))$$.

with $b=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.